# Augmented matrices in ConTeXt?

Tags: math-mode, context

In LaTeX, I could use:

```
\[
\left[\,\begin{array}{rr|r}2&-3&6\\ 3&4&-9\end{array}\,\right]
\]
```

However, in ConTeXt, especially if I want right-alignments of columns, I seem to have to use:

```
\startformula
  \left[\,\startmathmatrix[n=2,align={right,right}]
    \NC 2 \NC -3 \NR
    \NC 3 \NC 4 \NR
  \stopmathmatrix\;\right|
  \left.\startmathmatrix[n=2,align={right}]
    \NC 6 \NR
    \NC 9 \NR
  \stopmathmatrix\,\right]
\stopformula
```

which is extremely wordy and clumsy-looking (especially compared with the neat and succinct LaTeX).

So - what is the best way of typesetting augmented matrices in ConTeXt?

Thanks!

Comment: There was a module written by Giuseppe Bilotta, called `amsl`, that had support for a `\startarray ... \stoparray` feature that is supposed to be like that of the AMS Latex module.  If you google around you can find the implementation, but for some reason it is no longer on CTAN.

Comment: The `amsl` module is available at [contextgarden](http://modules.contextgarden.net/amsl), but I would be really surprised if it works with MkIV (IIR, it also does some font changes, and that interface has changed). The array code should still work.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a MWA of an idea mostly for Aditya to look at:

```
\unprotect
\def\dosetmatrixcolumn#1%
  {\letvalue{\??eq:\v!left :\number\eqaligncolumn}\hfil
   \letvalue{\??eq:\v!right:\number\eqaligncolumn}\hfil
   % this is new:
   \doif{#1}\v!rule  {\letvalue{\??eq:\v!left :\number\eqaligncolumn}\relax
                      \setvalue{\??eq:\v!right:\number\eqaligncolumn}%
                               {\kern -.5\mathalignmentparameter\c!distance
                                \vrule
                                \kern -.5\mathalignmentparameter\c!distance}}%
   \doif{#1}\v!left  {\letvalue{\??eq:\v!left :\number\eqaligncolumn}\relax
                      \letvalue{\??eq:\v!right:\number\eqaligncolumn}\hfil}%
   \doif{#1}\v!right {\letvalue{\??eq:\v!left :\number\eqaligncolumn}\hfil
                      \letvalue{\??eq:\v!right:\number\eqaligncolumn}\relax }%
   \doif{#1}\v!middle{\letvalue{\??eq:\v!left :\number\eqaligncolumn}\hfil
                      \letvalue{\??eq:\v!right:\number\eqaligncolumn}\hfil}}
\protect

\definemathmatrix
   [augmentedarray]
   [n=4,left={\left[\,},right={\,\right]},align={right,right,rule,right}]

\starttext

\startformula
  \startaugmentedarray
    \NC 2 \NC -3 \NC \NC 6 \NR
    \NC 3 \NC  4 \NC \NC 9 \NR
  \stopaugmentedarray
\stopformula

\stoptext
```

There are two things wrong with this bit of code:

- the internal macro `\dosetmatrixcolumn` needs redefinition which should be done in context core itself, not as part of a document.
- the `\NC \NC` is a little ugly.

still, it saves a lot of typing.

Comment: Isn't `\processaction` better than a bunch of `\doif`s?

Comment: I think that it is better to have a separate syntax for rules (and braces), something along the lines of `TABLE` macros.

Answer (score 1):

Not a real answer, but the following codes give the same result

```
\[
\left[\begin{array}{@{}rr|r@{}}2&-3&6\\ 3&4&-9\end{array}\right]
\]
\[
\left[\openup1\jot\offinterlineskip\vcenter{\halign{%
  \strut
  \hfil$#$\hskip\arraycolsep&
  \hskip\arraycolsep\hfil$#$\hskip\arraycolsep\kern-.2pt\vrule\kern-.2pt&
  \hskip\arraycolsep\hfil$#$\cr
  2&-3&6\cr
  3&4&-9\cr}}
\right]
\]
```

It's just a matter of teaching ConTeXt to do the `\halign`. Note that **amsmath** prefers tight spacing of the delimiters, as can be seen with the `bmatrix` environment, but that's a question of taste.